# how to a jvm load a project(many classes in it)

Tags: java, jvm, aop, cglib, jvmti

how to jvm load a project, including many classes in it? Does jvm has a class map of the whole project. How to jvm get the map of those classes? Can I get any class of this project at any time from the jvm, no matter the class is not loaded in jvm or it has finished its job and has been terminated? I know that it is possible to load class before start, and to get class during the class was running in jvm, but what about it is terminated. Does any one has any references? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. You are asking many questions. Be a bit more concise. What setup do you have and when do you want to achieve what in the lifecycle of a JVM? Are you already familiar with [class loading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)?

Comment: I am not familiar with class loading. After scan reading the link, I want to know the lifecycle of the class loader of a specific class. I want get the class, but I am afraid of it has terminated, so that I cant achieve its infomation.